# Stored procedure in Neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

I wanted to know if there is any Neo4j equivalent of a stored procedure? 
When I researched this, I came across `events`, but I found them more like triggers and not stored procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedures are available as capabilities CALLABLE from the Cypher language since version 3.0

- A first reference can be found here
  https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-30-stored-procedures
- A remarkable example, showing how graph can be processed in the large
  through procedure to achieve network clustering and community
  decetion, here
  http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2016/02/28/neo4j-a-procedure-for-the-slm-clustering-algorithm/

**EDIT**

As Neo4J 3.0 has been released in April'16, the stored procedure became an official, Apache 2.0 licensed, repository.

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/

Available procedures range from data manipulation/import to Spatial and complex graph algorithms (es. Page Rank, Dijkstra, Community detection, betweenness centrality , closeness centrality, etc)

Answer (score 5):

There are basically two techniques to extend a Neo4j server:

1. [Server plugins](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html) enrich the existing REST endpoints and
2. [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) allow to you create new REST endpoints

Both techniques require to write code in JVM (or other JVM language), package a jar file and deploy it to Neo4j server.

Comment: But unmanaged extensions are more versatile and easier to use (imho).

Comment: Neither server plugins nor unmanaged extensions provide the stored procedure functionality that Jack was looking for.

Comment: I disagree, stored procedures are basically some piece of code running on the server - that's exactly what unamanaged extensions or server plugins do.

Comment: thanks. these plug-ins seems to be a nearest match to stored procedure.

Comment: I hope one day we get access to those plugins through Cypher. In my experience neo4j server plugins are easy to make. But then the reliance on REST cripples their use, specially now that Cypher is increasingly becoming the primary way of accessing data in neo4j.

Comment: @retrography Do you find that Neo4j servers tend to have I/O as a bottleneck?  REST might not be as bad as you think unless you have a high transaction to active user ratio.

If you're saying that the plugins are basically useless in the context of a Cypher query though then that sounds like an issue.

Answer (score 2):

My answer here does not answer the question directly (Stefan's answer does just fine for that).  With that said, if any of you are considering writing server plugins (to get Stored Proc behavior) before your project is actually being used in production (which at the time of this writing is the vast majority of the Neo4j userbase), I strongly recommend **not** doing so.

Server plugins add architectural complexity to your project. You will require JVM developers to maintain them. Deploying or updating them can be tricky, and the associated source control methodologies are not intuitive. Neo4j doesn't require schema migrations, which makes your job as a developer easier.  Adding server plugins will no longer give you that benefit, and since it's not a mainstream use case of Neo4j, you'll be getting little help from the developer community, and improvements and bug fixes related around that function will be given lesser priority from the Neo4j team.

And all that would be for possibly a slight performance boost, or none at all.

"Stored Procedures" (or using server plugins as such) are an important feature to have in the context of performance tuning, but if your team is still two guys in a garage, don't even think about going down this path.